# Jersey - JAX-RS versions and validations not working

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-1.0

JSR-303 validations are not working for me.I am using below version of Jersey

```
    <jersey.version>1.2</jersey.version>
    <jaxrs.version>1.1.1</jaxrs.version>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

   public class Employee{
          @JsonProperty("name")
          @NotNull
          private String name;
     }

   @POST
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Produces({"application/json"})
   public void postTradeParties(@Valid Employee entity){
   }
```

If name is empty Post should not not happen.It should give 400 error.
Validation does not seem to work.Below is the entry in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ResourceConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet- class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> -->
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hsbc.net.dc.web.config.MyResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResourceConfig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Did u find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortuantely no, it's a legacy application.We were not allowed to change anything in web.xml.We did those validations without any framework